# Decoding Morse Live From Mic Input, using C# NAudio

Tags: c#, wpf, decode, naudio, morse-code

I have a listener class that listens to the Mic input:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Spectrogram.MicrophoneDemo
{
    public class Listener : IDisposable
    {
        public readonly int SampleRate;
        private readonly NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent wvin;
        public double AmplitudeFrac { get; private set; }
        public double TotalSamples { get; private set; }
        public double TotalTimeSec { get { return (double)TotalSamples / SampleRate; } }
        private readonly List<double> audio = new List<double>();
        public int SamplesInMemory { get { return audio.Count; } }

        public Listener(int deviceIndex, int sampleRate)
        {
            SampleRate = sampleRate;
            wvin = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent
            {
                DeviceNumber = deviceIndex,
                WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(sampleRate, bits: 16, channels: 1),
                BufferMilliseconds = 20
            };
            wvin.DataAvailable += OnNewAudioData;
            wvin.StartRecording();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            wvin?.StopRecording();
            wvin?.Dispose();
        }

        private void OnNewAudioData(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args)
        {
            int bytesPerSample = wvin.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
            int newSampleCount = args.BytesRecorded / bytesPerSample;
            double[] buffer = new double[newSampleCount];
            double peak = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < newSampleCount; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(args.Buffer, i * bytesPerSample);
                peak = Math.Max(peak, buffer[i]);
            }
            lock (audio)
            {
                audio.AddRange(buffer);
            }
            AmplitudeFrac = peak / (1 << 15);
            TotalSamples += newSampleCount;
        }

        public double[] GetNewAudio()
        {
            lock (audio)
            {
                double[] values = new double[audio.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    values[i] = audio[i];
                audio.RemoveRange(0, values.Length);
                return values;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My next step is to go through the Samples and gathering the morse 'dit' and 'dat'.

I have never worked with audio data before and would only like to know
how I would be able to achieve decoding morse patterns using the sample data?

Comment: What do you know about the samples? Can they have varying Noise-Levels or are they relatively clean? Assuming they are clean, you could measure Amplitude and binarize: If Amplitude is > X => 1, If <= X => 0. So you get streams of 00001111100011111111000011 and so on. Then you can measure lengths of 1-fields. If I remeber correctly then "dat"s should be at least double the length of "dits", well there are rules you can look up and apply. It will be a bit of math, though ;)

Comment: Yes, the samples will probably have varying noise levels, thus I want to include a noise filter as well at a later stage. I am familiar with the morse rules, and I'm only looking to decode the morse samples at a frequency between 500Hz and 2kHz. I will try your solution, adding an extra few conditions.